# how to retrieve day month and year from Timestamp(long format)

Tags: java, datetime

I need to retrieve day year and month from a timestamp object as long numbers:

```
public long getTimeStampDay()
    {

            String iDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        .format(new Date(born_date.getDate())); 
         .....

              return day; //just the day

    }

public long getTimeStampMonth()
    {
    String iDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        .format(new Date(born_date.getDate())); 
         .....

              return month; //just month

    }

public long getTimeStampYear()
    {
    String iDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        .format(new Date(born_date.getDate())); 
         .....

              return year; //just year
    }
```

`born_date` is a timestamp object.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
long timestamp = bornDate.getTime();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
return cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

There are calendar fields for each property you need.

Alternatively you can use [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(bornDate.getDate());
return datetime.getYear();
```

Comment: Hello, in my case, the variable "bornDate" type is "java.sql.Timestamp".
I would like to retrieve the year from "bornDate".
"getYear()" is deprecated but "getDate()" is deprecated too...
So, what should be done? Thx.

Comment: "bornDate" type is "java.sql.Timestamp".
The following code does the trick: 
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
calendar.setTime(bornDate);  
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

Answer (score 5):

A little refreshment of this well-accepted thread that is a bit outdated by now.

Back in the day, Java 8 introduced Date and Time API which makes extracting much cleaner.

Let's assume that `bornDate` is instance of `LocalDateTime`.

```java
bornDate.getDayOfMonth(); // extracts day of month
bornDate.getMonth();      // extracts month
bornDate.getYear();       // extracts year
```

Oracle reference: [Java SE 8 Date and Time](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html)

Comment: And to create a LocalDateTime from a long epoch time you can do something like this:

        `LocalDateTime ldt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epoch).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();`

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you are using a dateformat in each method, you can use a different format string in each. For example:

```
public long getTimeStampDay()
    {

            String day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd")
        .format(new Date(born_date.getDate())); 
         .....

              return Long.parseLong(day); //just the day

    }
```

Answer (score -4):

This method returns the day, date, year and time:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score -5):

I found a simple way to do that:

```
born_date.getDay();
born_date.getMonth();
born_date.getYear();
```

even if method getDay getMonth and getYear are deprecated. 
I think that Bozho solution is the best one.

Comment: `born_date.getDay()` -> as of jdk 1.1 deprecated. same for getMonth() and getYear(). use @Bozho solution

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot : it links to the answer already provided by Bozho. Possibly is just a comment to it.