# How to get year, month,day from given timestamp like "1459233289187"

Tags: java

I am calculating timestamp from system time as

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

in java.

Later, i want to calculate year , moth and date from this time stamp.
is there any way to do so?

Comment: `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())`

Comment: Did you try searching for another question like this one first?

Comment: You need to calculate this with respect to a specific timezone. There are multiple values for year, month or day of month from a timestamp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262570/how-to-retrieve-day-month-and-year-from-timestamplong-format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```